# Caching the base docker image for faster pulls

Tags: docker, docker-layer

I have a `n` docker files each corresponding to one image with layers from `1..m` common to all of them. The steps specifically includes pulling the base image from a public registry, installing the bare minimum essentials for application running. Due to nature of use case after a periodic interval I am downloading a different docker image that has same base and initial installations but a different application layer.

Question 1:
The docker pull time for some of them is very large based on layers after the layer `m` or the common layers. Is there a way to cache these first `m` layers (common installations) so that I can save on some time for subsequent pulls?

Question 2:
Is it possible to pull only the subsequent layers meaning from layer m onwards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking is exactly what docker does. You can refer to the [storage driver docs](https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/#sharing-promotes-smaller-images) which talks about this exact situation

> When you use docker pull to pull down an image from a repository, or when you create a container from an image that does not yet exist locally, each layer is pulled down separately, and stored in Docker’s local storage area, which is usually /var/lib/docker/ on Linux hosts.

It goes on to talk about your exact case

> Now imagine that you have two different Dockerfiles. You use the first
> one to create an image called acme/my-base-image:1.0.

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM alpine
RUN apk add --no-cache bash
```

> The second one is based on acme/my-base-image:1.0, but has some
> additional layers:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM acme/my-base-image:1.0
COPY . /app
RUN chmod +x /app/hello.sh
CMD /app/hello.sh
```

> The second image contains all the layers from the first image, plus
> new layers created by the COPY and RUN instructions, and a read-write
> container layer. Docker already has all the layers from the first
> image, so it does not need to pull them again. The two images share
> any layers they have in common.

Comment: Thanks Chris, exactly what I was looking for. Do you know if this is still valid if we build the individual images using --squash option? I am guessing it will be not but still wanted to check.

Comment: Anyways found this: excellent read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47011097/docker-squash-and-layer-which-layers-are-merged-and-which-are-still-shared