# Is there a way to squash only layers other than base in docker image?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-build

I have a base image B and few layers on top of it (1 ..K.. M) is there a way to squash only the layers from K to M excluding the first 1 .. K layers? Can we do it if it is not a multi-stage build scenario? Meaning layer K is not base for subsequent layers?

I was referring to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47017406/7103753) but was not able to relate the output of squash as it has multiple layers whereas I am building an image using --squash but getting just a single layer.

Any help appreciated.